# Is there a way to copy and paste columns from another spreadsheet by matching the columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two spreadsheets, one (Spreadsheet A) containing First Name, Last Name, Date of Birth, E-Mail, Phone Number, and other columns. I have another spreadsheet (Spreadsheet B), which can contain any combination of these columns in any order. I'm hoping to match whatever columns are in spreadsheet B and copy them directly into spreadsheet A.

For example,

Let's say my spreadsheet B has the columns First Name, E-mail, and Date of Birth. I'd like to copy the information in these columns, paste and have them automatically reordered the way they are in spreadsheet A. I realize you can separately select each column in a specific order and paste it, but was wondering if there was any alternative ways to go about this, by matching the columns across two spreadsheets.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. In the second spreadsheet, filled with columns empty except for headers, use the following formula in each column of the second spreadsheet:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$E$7, 0,  COLUMN(XLOOKUP(G1, $A$1:$E$1, $A$1:$E$1) ) )
```

It assumes the first spreadsheet has headers in row 1, that spreadsheet 2 has identical headers for whatever columns it has, in any order, and that the first spreadsheet's data is in columns A:E beginning in row 2.

Since I did not write it to go between spreadsheets and did write it for clarity, you will not see full-blown multiple spreadsheet addressing, just cell and range addressing. Just edit it for the correct address and range information. It also assumes the headers in spreadsheet 2 are in row 1, and begin in column G. It would be incredible coincidental if that were so! So edit the "G1" reference to be the header of the first column.

Place the formula in the first column and edit for addresses. NOTE that EVERY address for a range is completely absolute:  `$`'s before each part of the address. For instance, $A$2:$E$7... one column and one row value in the first half, same in the second half, so FOUR `$`'s. That is very important. One other thing about the ranges selected is important, but more on that shortly.

What the formula does is that `XLOOKUP()` takes the second spreadsheet's column header and looks it up in the first spreadsheet's header row. One figures the data in the first spreadsheet begins in column A, but that could be wrong. Might be any old column. Could be a different row as well. The row is a simple edit, but the exact column... that's where that other important thing comes into play.

Let's say it is columns A:G. So the formula returns 1, 2, ... 7 depending upon what column matches. Easy, eh? But what if the data begins in column R and goes a ways to the right? Then it returns the same thing, except you now have to adjust the value for the fact it doesn't start in column 1, but rather in column 18. Bothersome, and hard to maintain if a column outside the range gets added or deleted, maybe column F getting deleted.

But, if you don't start the range with column R, like maybe R1:X1, but rather column A, the lookup that finds column R's header will report back with 18, not 1. So no adjustment is needed. Of course, the header text can't occur in any of those extra cells, but that isn't usually a problem in things like this. So it eases your task, and understanding it a year from now when it needs adjustment.

So, when editing the two ranges at the end — **notice that they are identical so make sure they end up identical** — start with column A, even if it is completely outside the range the information is in, and continue as far right as the data does, in fact, continue a dozen or two more columns. If they ever get used, then no edits needed! Easy. If they never do, they will also never have text matching a header in the second spreadsheet, and in fact, even if they do by some odd chance, the lookup finds the first one that exists so never notices the second on in the unused area.

Anyway, the `XLOOKUP()` looks at the text in the header for the column it is in. It takes that and goes to the first spreadsheet, looks in the header row for the same text, and after finding it, `COLUMN()` figures out the column number it is in.

That column number is passed outward to the `INDEX()` function. That function takes up to four parameters, but only the first three matter here:

1. The range it is returning data from. This is the entire data range in the first spreadsheet. Let's say, for a second, that it is A2:E7, like in the formula. If you did not use extra columns in the `XLOOKUP()`, then use exactly A2:E7. If you added, say, six columns to the `XLOOKUP()` part, planning for the future, then make it those six columns wider, so A:E AND six more columns:  A:K, so A2:K7 in this example. Those columns again have no bad effects, so match what you do now to what you did in the lookup. Or you might have a perplexing problem to troubleshoot one day! Be sure to remember the left side as well. If the data begins in column R, still use column A as the starting column for the data. That way the header column's number will be right.

IF you had spreadsheets that matched MUCH more closely, at least much more particularly, you would have not done the trick starting the lookups in column A. But the very freeform nature of where things are, actually in BOTH spreadsheets, leads me to this much more general solution. If you have much more regularity to things, you can abridge a bit of my generality here.

2. The row or rows you want. Since you don't do anything... special... choosing the column/s (believe it or not, there's nothing "special" about a straightforward lookup like you are doing), you can use a simple "0" here to let Excel know you want ALL the rows there are. If you had done something special, you'd have to do a teensy bit more to explicitly explain to Excel you want all the rows. You could actually simply not even enter anything, so it would be two commas there (`,,`) instead of the `,0,` you see. Many find a weird thrill doing that, but I like to have something there because once in a while it avoids odd errors when later edits happen, but MOSTLY because it is much easier to spot and see what's going on a year from creation.
3. Your lookup goes in this third parameter:  it found the header in the first spreadsheet that matched to one in the second spreadsheet and calculated its column number. And that is the exact column you need here.

You can do other things, using the above approach still, for example, maybe you'd like to do the work of telling Excel what column to use. Easily done, but you emphasized the freeform nature of column correspondence so I have set it up for letting Excel do the work.

At any rate, the results will `SPILL` down the second spreadsheet's column. Copy the formula to the right as far as there are headers and those columns will fill too.

If the column gets moved in the first spreadsheet, it doesn't matter since the lookup will still find the column and return its correct column number to `INDEX()`.

I'm just out of time for this one, so I did not have a chance to work through the weirdnesses involved in order to make the formula `SPILL` to the right as well as down. The obvious using, say, G1:J1 in the lookup instead of a single cell, generated difficulties. Maybe someone else will add that detail for you.